# change image on click on mobile device

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, mouseover, mouseout

I want the simplest script to change an image/button from one image to another image of the same size. Basically, the same button with different colors.

The button is on a website which will be only accessed by mobile devices. It will link to another website, but I already know how to do that. I've tried using the mouse event scripting I'm familiar with, but I still cannot get this to work. I want it to be as basic as possible.

Here's the script I'm currently using:

```
<a href=""><img onclick="this.src='emergency-down.png'" onmouseout="this.src='emergency-up.png'" src="emergency-up.png" /></a>
```

Comment: By the way, here's the script I was using.
<a href=""><img onclick="this.src='emergency-down.png'" onmouseout="this.src='emergency-up.png'" src="emergency-up.png" /></a>

Answer (score 0):

As long as you just want this to happen once, change `<a href="">` to `<a href="#">`.